# How to overlap 2 nodes on exactly the same location?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have the following `graphviz` code:

```
digraph G {

  x [label = "X", shape = cylinder, width = 1, height = 1, style = filled, fillcolor = lightblue]
    
}
```

which produces:

[image]

Now, I want to make another cylinder node on exactly the same location and I want its height to be a bit longer than the other one. The difference should have the red colour. For example, something like this (just a manual attempt to roughly show what i mean):

[image]

How can I achieve this?

**My attempt**:

```
digraph G {
  node [shape=cylinder, width=1, style=filled];
  
  // Node 1
  x [label="X", height=1, color=lightblue, pos="0,0!"];
  
  // Node 2 (overlapping with Node 1)
  y [label="Y", height=2, color=red, pos="0,0!"];

  // Invisible edge to make the nodes overlap
  edge [style=invis];
  y -> x;
}
```

which produces:

[image]

Comment: Is this to be part of a larger graph, or just two cylinders?

Comment: @sroush it does not matter, as long as it looks like a long graph that has most of it filled with "lightblue" and the rest is "red". So it should give an illusion of a filled bucket where the empty part is red :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**neato** can do what you want, but you have to adjust the **pos** values to overlap correctly (**pos** sets the center of the node)

use this command: `neato -Tpng myfile.gv >myfile.png`

```
digraph G {
  layout=neato // added for javascript use

  node [shape=cylinder, width=1, style=filled];

  // Node 2 (overlapping with Node 1)
  y [label="", height=2, color=red pos="2,2!" ]  

  // Node 1  (smaller on top)
  x [label="X", height=1, color=lightblue, pos="2,1.5!"];
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: I'm using [graphviz online](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/) and there it does not work

Comment: Example has been edited to work w/ online version of Graphviz